# How to get my selenium-standalone to start - selenium-standalone start

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

I am trying to run a test script in WebDriverIO except I am having an extremely difficult time.

I have cloned the code from wdio-cucumber-framework and cannot get selenium-standalone start working

Error is below - seems to be a geckodriver issue except I can't find anywhere on how to provide a fix.

> /Users/adam/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.1/lib/node_modules/selenium-standalone/bin/selenium-standalone:79
>           throw err;
>           ^
>
> Error: Missing
>   /Users/adam/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.1/lib/node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/geckodriver/0.23.0-x64-geckodriver
>       at /Users/adam/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.1/lib/node_modules/selenium-standalone/lib/check-paths-existence.js:15:20
>       at suppressedCallback (fs.js:200:5)
>       at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:141:20) sira-JSS774:wdio-cucumber-framework sira$

I've tried different versions - I have installed geckodriver. It is not available in the directory this directory does not exist - .selenium/geckodriver/0.23.0-x64-geckodriver

Expecting from "selenium-standalone start" to work in the terminal as expected.

Answer (score 1):

selenium-standalone requires you to install the drivers using `selenium-standalone install`

This will download and install the drivers to the directory `/path/to/node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/****`

After this step, `selenium-standalone start` will start the driver servers correctly.

Side note, I have this installed as a devDependancy with my project. This allows me to run the CLI with the `npx` as a prefix (kind of like sudo)

Here is a step-by-step for my config:

1. install as a devDep `npm i -D selenium-standalone`
2. install web drivers `npx selenium-standalone install`
3. start the web drivers in a detached process `npx selenium-standalone start &`
4. run my tests `npm test`

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same issues today. As [per their docs](https://github.com/webdriverio/selenium-standalone/blob/main/docs/CLI.md) the solution is to install all driver binaries (I had to do it even if not going to use them), just that I can make the server start.

```
yarn selenium-standalone install --singleDriverInstall=chrome --drivers.chrome.version=95.0.4638.69
...
yarn selenium-standalone install --singleDriverInstall=geckodriver
yarn selenium-standalone install --singleDriverInstall=msedgedriver
```

Then running `yarn selenium-standalone start --drivers.chrome.version=95.0.4638.69` solves it.